# Stop IntelliJ IDEA updating copyright on specific files

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there any way I can stop IntelliJ IDEA from updating the copyright notice in specific files? I just went to do a `git commit` and noticed that it had updated the copyright notice in `lightbox.js` which I don't want — it's not mine!

Ideally I'd like to mark a "3rd party" sub-directory as being excluded from copyright updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Settings | Copyright, find a scope used, modify this scope (Settings | Scopes) so that it excludes your "3rd party" sub-directory.